# Track completion through Facebook Share dialog Url

Tags: facebook, share

I am using the share dialog url to share a page from both my website and emails. But I'm not sure how to track completion of the share dialog popup.

Here is the link i am using, unfortunately this doesn't provide feedback on if they complete the share. I also tried adding the @traveshoot to the quote parameter to link to the facebook business page, but it just comes through as plain text. I even tried adding the Hashtag to the post, but that doesn't come up in the facebook business page notifications tab.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=xxxxx&display=popup&href=https://portal.travelshoot.com/Home/Images/?galleryId=xxxxxxx@quote=@Travelshoot
```

Because i am sharing in email I am limited to non-scripted solutions.

Does anyone know how i can change the url to allow completion tracking or any other method that will work?  Is this even possible?

Comment: You would need publish_actions permission from the user that is logged in to your app, then you could get the id of the newly created post back. Although I am not sure if that works for the URL version, or the scripted one only. (Hope you are aware that rewarding users for sharing, or gating content behind it, is not allowed.)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on the URL version as the person is not logged in. Have already looked down that avenue.  And read that statement in the Facebook policies.  This is just to get usage patterns and metrics so that we can make improvements to the application.